# Docker eats /var space how I can save some?

Tags: docker, disk-usage

> Because there are some good comments on this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/527632/173648) I thought that they could be good answers and beneficial, in this particular question.
>
> Therefore in order to be able to be more beneficial for the community, I thought to be able to get answered here.

In my gnu/linux system I have the `/var` as big as 20G but due to use with docker and the development of custom docker images the `/var` takes the 90% of the space so how can I same some space in `/var`?

I originally thought to do some backup as this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/527632/173648) says, then repartition the `/var`. But seems too laborious to me. Is there a safer and less time-consuming alternative?

Comment: Clear dangling images and such? Have tried checking which images are taking the most space?

Comment: Well this is a solution that you can make a full answer of it.

Comment: Have you done `docker system prune` recently?

Comment: How is creating a backup not safe?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Nope I have not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have not done so for a while, then run `docker system prune`. It will run the garbage collector, and free a lot of disk space.

Note it may cause more work to be done next time you do something (such as build, pull, …), but should not remove anything that can not be got back.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to rsync the folder `/var/lib/docker` into a larger disk/partition. In my case, the partitions that contain `/home/` has some heaps of free space; therefore I followed these steps:

1. I made a dedicated folder in `/home/` named `docker`

   ```
   mkdir /home/docker
   ```
2. Using `rsync`, I copied the data to `/home/docker`

   ```
   rsync -av /var/lib/docker/ /home/docker
   ```

   This makes `/home/docker` an exact copy of `/var/lib/docker`.  Note that the trailing slash on the source directory is deliberate.  Without it, you would get a `docker` directory inside `/home/docker`.
3. I checked how the rsync process went:

   ```
   ls -l /home/docker
   ```
4. I terminated the docker daemon: (I'm using Ubuntu; therefore, using `service` was working fine, also using `systemctl` will do the job in most distros)

   ```
   sudo service docker stop
   ```
5. Remove the `/var/lib/docker`

   ```
   rm -rf /var/lib/docker
   ```
6. Symlink into `/home/docker`

   ```
   sudo ln -s /home/docker /var/lib/docker
   ```
7. Start docker once again:

   ```
   sudo service docker start
   ```